Why does my Swagger from Spring-WebMVC not working?
I'm trying to add swagger for my application, wrote annotations Tag and Operation for my controllers, add custom context path, but page is not opening.
I tried different versions of Swagger. Fox, WebMvc etc, but none of them worked out.
<dependency>
     <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
     <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
    <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.0</version>
</dependency>


server.servlet.context-path=/api/v1/
springdoc.swagger-ui.path=/docs/swagger

As an example, it is one of my controllers:
import application.models.event.EventCategory;
import application.services.event.EventCategoryService;
import io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.Operation;
import io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.tags.Tag;
import jakarta.validation.Valid;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

import java.util.List;

@RestController
@Tag(name = "Category API", description = "all categories API")
@RequestMapping("/categories")
public class CategoryController {
    private final EventCategoryService service;

    public CategoryController(EventCategoryService service) {
        this.service = service;
    }

    @PostMapping()
    @Operation(summary = "create category")
    public ResponseEntity<?> create(@Valid @RequestBody EventCategory category) {
        service.createEventCategory(category);
        return ResponseEntity.ok("Category is created");
    }

I go to http://localhost:8080/api/v1/docs/swagger, and nothing, just white page.
No errors in console, nothing also in network.
